# Can't Solve Error

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am getting following error while updating with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

at the bottom and even i cant able to update or add repository in software and updates.

```
E:The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu-GNOME 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412) zesty Release' does not have a Release file.,
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http ://deb. torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http ://ppa.launchpad.net/damien-moore/codeblocks-stable/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http ://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/myppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have certain repositories that don't have `zesty releases`, so got to `System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Other Software` and look for and `uncheck` those repositories. On closing you will be asked to update you repo information, similar to doing `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`.

[image]